# User's contact list structure

Tags: sql, database, data-structures, nosql

I have users, each of whom can add another to his contacts list.

user structure:

```
id, name, phone, ...
```

If one user adds another user to his contacts list, he can change name of the user being added.

I have function like this:

```
getUsers(self_id, user_ids)
```

*self_id* - current user and *user_ids* - list of user ids

I need to get list of users and change their names based on current user contacts list.

Which database and data structure i should use to store this data?

Comment: analyze this https://github.com/jabberd2/jabberd2/blob/master/tools/db-setup.pgsql

Comment: @filiprem and what i had to find there?

Comment: the generic model of user contact list, called "user roster" in Jabber / XMPP protocol. Just use this model and you will be fine.